# How to click on text link inside of text view-appium in Android?

Tags: selenium, automation, appium

Here is a screenshot:

[image: click to open screenshot]

How can I click on those links? I didn't get any specific id's for those links

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Using xpath you could do somthing like

```
driver.findelement(By.Xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Link Name' )]")).click();
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

See if the element exists first when you try to assert

`puts wait_true { exists { find_element(:xpath, "//*[@text='#{Link name}']").click  } }`

If this returns true, then try to assert the element by `find_element(:xpath, "//*[@text='#{link name}']"`

Alternatively, you can use `id` which is recommended `find_element(id: "id name").click`

I see the id name to be `termsAndConditions` as per the screenshot. It is always recommended that you ask the development team to provide id's